# Applescript Random Delay

Tags: applescript

I need to play a sound at random times throughout the day.

How can I create a random delay function, that then plays the file through the system audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
on run {}
    my doit()
end run

on doit()
    display dialog "hello world"
end doit

on idle {}
    set ran to random number from 0 to 10
    doit()
    return ran
end idle
```

be sure to save it as stay open application

Comment: @bigmapideas your welcome please don't forget to accept 8 ^ )

Answer (score 3):

**delay *x*** takes an integer for an argument.

**random number from *a* to *b*** generates a random integer between values a and b